# Meteor cannot update mongo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I'm having a strange problem were the below line of code will not run in my JavaScript, however runs fine in the *-meteor mongo* terminal

```
resources.update({system : "booster1"},{$set:{output : 10}});
```

Anybody know why this wouldn't work in JavaScript, but would work in the terminal?

Here is the rest of my code

```
Template.FDO.events({
    'change #booster1OutputSlider': function(){
        var value = $('#booster1OutputSlider').val();
        resources.update({system : "booster1"},{$set:{output : value}});
    }
});
```

I have tested value to make sure it returns a usable variable, it works just as it should.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=[**Edit**]=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

My resources collection is defined in another .js file in my *lib* folder.  The code for which is below :

```
resources = new Meteor.Collection("Resources");
```

Comment: Does it throw any sort of error? Or does it just not update?

Comment: @TimC My JavaScript freezes on that line, and won't complete anything past that line.  So the problem is with the actual update statement itself.  But as far as my meteor terminal goes, it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: What happens if you use strings as keys (`"system"` instead of `system`)?

Comment: am not sure. This works fine in my project `resources.update({system : "booster1"},{$set:{output : value}},{upsert:true});` just try

Comment: @royhowie still not working, but this changing it doesn't throw and exception or anything.

Comment: @BlueBells Unfortunately, that doesn't work ether.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @IanWise does your `insert()` function works?

Comment: @BlueBells my `insert()` function does work, along with my `find()`.

Comment: What does value equal? Console.log it out and see if the value names sense?

Comment: @TimC Interesting, I get a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Console` in the console when I try to `Console.Log(value);`

Comment: @IanWise `console.log(value)` is right one, not `Console.Log(value)`

Comment: I think you have to create an object like `var obj = {};` then `obj["output"]=value;`, and use that object in update query `resources.update({system : "booster1"},{$set:obj});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And we've got your problem! Your current permissions aren't allowing you to update the document. So you can either add in some logic to find the documents ID, and select it by that ID, or you can modify your permissions. If definitely recommend the first route as opposed to the second for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Where/how are you defining "resources"? You might see some issues if you don't properly define, publish, and subscribe to the database. It would explain why it works in mongo, but not in your client side js.

Comment: I am defining my resources in another .js file named database, in my lib folder.  I'll post the code for that above.

Comment: @IanWise Can you try adding something to the insert statement? Add this update call?      `resources.update({system : "booster1"},{$set:{output : 10}}, function(err, res){ console.log(err || res ) });`

Comment: When I add that to my code, I get the following error in my console : `Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]`

Comment: Thank you!  If you post your comment as an answer, I would be very happy to upvote and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

**Template:**

```
<template name="FDO">
   <input name="myInput" type="text" />
</template>
```

**JS:**

```
Template.FDO.events({
    'change [name="myInput"]': function(event, template){
        var value = event.target.myInput.value;
        resources.update({system : "booster1"},{$set:{output : value}});
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to fix the problem.  I think that the problem lies more with the actual update statement, then with value, because `resources.update({system : "booster1"},{$set:{output : 20}});` does not work.  Thank you for your answer though.